# Angular directive to match multiple attributes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Can I define an angular directive so that it would match multiple similar terms 
i.e.

```
angular.module('search').directive('platformPreload', function() {
  return {
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
    }
  }
}
```

Would match both the following:

```
<div platform-preload-terms="[]"></div>
<div platform-preload-suggestions="[]"></div>
```

Comment: You could set `<div platform-preload class="test" platform-terms="[]"></div>" and then just link the `platform-terms` or `platform-suggestions` in the directive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no wildcard directive declaration.

But you can isolate the function and repeat the definition:

```
angular.module('search')
    .directive('platformPreload', PlatFunction)
    .directive('platformPreloadSuggestions', PlatFunction)


PlatFunction() {
    return {
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create isolated scopes for the directive which will allow you to use these attributes in the isolated scope on the directive. Like this:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('appController', function($scope) {

})

.directive('platformPreload', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: {
      platformTerms: '@',
      platformSuggestions: '@'
    },
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      console.log('DIRECTIVE');
      if ($scope.platformTerms) {
        console.log($scope.platformTerms);
      }
      if ($scope.platformSuggestions) {
        console.log($scope.platformSuggestions);
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="appController">
  <div platform-preload platform-terms="These are the terms"></div>
  <div platform-preload platform-suggestions="These are the suggestions"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This is a valid solution, but I prefer to keep the HTML cleaner

Comment: Yeah. Might be more suitable in other situations.